# Search data from SQL Database using multiple textbox and a Search Button

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I Have a jQuery dialog with 4 Textbox and a Search Button. I want to search a value from my database then display that value in  GridView each textbox has a string `@firstname` `@lastname` `@address` `@mobile` user may put a value in any of the textbox and if they click the `btnSearch_Click` value will display in a GridView.

I hope you understand my problem(not good at english and new in programming).

Problem: If user enter a value in any of the textbox value will display in gridview and dialog should close

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#Searchprod").dialog({
            appendTo: "form",
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 630,
            height: 350,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true
        });

        $("#btnupregSearch").click(function () {
            $("#Searchprod").dialog("open");
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

dialog w/ textbox and button:

```
<div id="Searchprod" title="Search User">
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="Searchpanel" >
<ContentTemplate>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label class="label">By First Name</label></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtfn" runat="server" class="basetxt" ></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label class="label">By Last Name</label></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtln" runat="server" class="basetxt" ></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label class="label">By Address</label></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtadd" runat="server" class="basetxt"></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label class="label">By Mobile</label></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtmobile" runat="server" class="basetxt" ></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><table>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server"  CausesValidation="false" Text="Search" class="submitbtn" onclick="btnSearch_Click" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:UpdateProgress ID="updateprogress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="Searchpanel" cla>
        <ProgressTemplate></ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

this is what I tried but i think its not working

Button:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("find", con);
        com.Parameters.Add("@firstname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtfn.Text;
        com.Parameters.Add("@lastname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtln.Text;
        com.Parameters.Add("@address", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtadd.Text;
        com.Parameters.Add("@mobile", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtmobile.Text;
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        dt.Clear();
        sqlda.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The updatepanel needs to be on the outside of div#Searchprod.  The way you have it now, I don't think div#Searchprod will close.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="Searchpanel" >
<ContentTemplate>
<div id="Searchprod" title="Search User">

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label class="label">By First Name</label></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtfn" runat="server" class="basetxt" ></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label class="label">By Last Name</label></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtln" runat="server" class="basetxt" ></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label class="label">By Address</label></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtadd" runat="server" class="basetxt"></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label class="label">By Mobile</label></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtmobile" runat="server" class="basetxt" ></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><table>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server"  CausesValidation="false" Text="Search" class="submitbtn" onclick="btnSearch_Click" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:UpdateProgress ID="updateprogress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="Searchpanel" cla>
        <ProgressTemplate></ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</ContentTemplate>

</div>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: I'm getting a new error `The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.`  `con.Open();`

Comment: You should check that variable 'strConnString' is being set somewhere.  I can't tell from your code that is is.